# geolocation not working on google chrome in IRAN country in Chrome

Tags: reactjs

In my React project, I am taking as inputs "Lat" and "Long" from user .I'm using geolocation to get user location. These changes are working fine with all browsers but not Chrome.
By using  VPN and changing my IP, Chrome started working but this IP number is not real since my location changed.

Please help me to solve this issue or give me suggestion to try another package or Direction
thanks :)

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function LocationInput({ Location, setLocation }) {
   useEffect(() => {
     if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
       console.log("Available");
     } else {
       console.log("Not Available");
     }
   }, []);
  const Handellocation = () => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
      console.log(position.coords.latitude);
      console.log(position.coords.longitude);
      setLocation({
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        long: position.coords.longitude,
        ButtonText: "find you !",
        ButtonColor: "#50C878",
      });
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p className="text">get locatin</p>
      <div className="location">
        <button
          onClick={Handellocation}
          style={{ backgroundColor: Location.ButtonColor }}
        >
          {Location.ButtonText}
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: kindly initialize your const [location, setLocation] object.

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens because of some countries being blacklisted for certain Google APIs, hence chrome wont support this. You need to work around with a different data-source ( DB/API/pollyfill)

Reference to the blacklisting: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/maps-prohibited-territories